Why is the trace of a positive semi-definite operator times a projector non-negative?
I'm reading a textbook at the moment, and I'm struggling to understand this

This is an aside for a separate proof and there is no more context given to this. I'm assuming it would be something along the lines of BQ being a positive semi-definite operator, thus it has non-negative eigenvalues and so a non-negative trace. I can't seem to justify to myself though why $BQ$ would be positive semi-definite.

Using $P=P^2$, $P=P^\top$ and rotation property of traces :
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Tr}[B P] &= \operatorname{Tr}[B P^2]\\
&= \operatorname{Tr}[B P P^\top]\\
&=\operatorname{Tr}[P^\top B P]
\end{align*}
and $P^\top BP$ is positive semi-definite.
